# why is rename not currently available

Tags: visual-studio-2010, rename

I *have* seen and used a `rename` feature in Visual Studio 2010.

However when editing code in C++ mode, I see no "Refactor" menu, and the CTRL+R CTRL+R command produces the following error message:

> The key combination (Ctrl+R, Ctrl+R) is bound to command (Rename...) which is not currently available.

**Eclipse** seems to have got this right.  Is there no rename feature in VS 2010 for VC++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there no rename feature in VS 2010 for VC++?

That is correct. None of the refactoring features work for C++ projects (C# and VB only). If you want these things, you need to use a third party plugin, such as [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/).

Comment: Sadly, Billy ONeal is correct. Like many, I had hoped for enhanced support and improvements for C++ projects with each subsequent VS release, but if anything, they just keep getting worse in favor of C#/.NET. :(

Comment: @Syntech: Well, they **did** make C++ a first-class project (that is, MSBuild), and they did fix intellisense in 2010.